# When fetching FB Insights in Ad Account, data like ad_name, ad_id, adset_id, adset_name are Empty

Tags: php

Using facebook/php-ads-sdk 2.11

Why can't I retrieved ad_id, adset_id, adset_name even though I included
them in my fields to fetch?

Sample Code

```
$account = new AdAccount('act_' . $this->account_id);
    $fields = array(
        'spend',
        'clicks',
        'impressions',
        'campaign_name',
        'campaign_id',
        'inline_link_clicks',
        'actions',
        'ad_name',
        'ad_id',
        'adset_id',
        'adset_name',
        'account_id',
        'account_name',
    );

    $param = $this->filters;
    $param['level'] = 'campaign';

    $cursor = $account->getInsights($fields, $param);
```